# Download file that lives elsewhere on the harddrive

Tags: c#, asp.net

Have an aspx page that displays files to a user for download.
These files can be any extension and live outside of the wwwroot folder.
They are displayed in a treeview.
I would like the user to be able to download any file they click on.

I have tried the following but it's only giving me the aspx page.

parent.Text is the folder where the file lives. node.Text is the filename.
so this would contain something like c:\dir\text.txt

```
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", String.Format("attachment; filename={0}", Path.Combine(parent.Text, node.Text)));
```

Comment: here is a good question.. when the user clicks on the file node are you correctly getting the filename at that time.. you will need to make sure that if it's stored on the Serverside, that you are capturing the correct path something like this is where you want to assign the file that clicked or selected from the treeview node `System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath`

Comment: Can you not add a handler and have a link in each item of the treeview to that handler.  For example have a handler stream back the file. You could get each file via an Id on the query string perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The filename header value indicates the name to present to the users browser (not the actual path to the file).

In order for the user to receive the file, you have to output it to the response.  The [TransmitFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12s31dhy%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) method helps greatly with this.

```
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", String.Format("attachment; filename={0}", node.Text));

Response.TransmitFile(Path.Combine(parent.Text, node.Text));

Response.End();
```

Comment: Would it not be better to have a dedicated file handler so as not to mess around with headers and wot not of the ASPX page?

Comment: I suspect there are many solutions, but the most straight forward answer to the specific problem is that the OP is not actually transmitting the file's contents.

Comment: If it gets the job done! Sorry I should've just posted a solution, I wasnt trying to be a smart-alec!

Answer (score 0):

Ok so in light of what I was saying.

Add a link on your treeview node so that when clicked it requests a handler named something like "fileHandler" with the ID of the file it relates to in the query string.

For example, when rolling over a node you will have something like "[your website name]/filehandler.ashx?fileid="guid|id"

And then implement your handler as per:

http://aspnetupload.com/Quickstart/Download-From-File.aspx

Some of the advantages when using a handler include not incurring the cost of the page lifecycle for the download (i.e no wasted postbacks on the page before jumping out and altering headers) and your file-serving capability is in it own place.